GitHub Actions: Is it possible to read or 'cat' the $GITHUB_ENV file?
I want to read all of the env vars that are stored in the $GITHUB_ENV file during a GitHub Actions job. When I cat $GITHUB_ENV, I get an empty output. But if I cat any other file, it works as expected.
Is it possible to cat the $GITHUB_ENV and/or $GITHUB_OUTPUT? Are there any patterns that let you read the contents of these files, besides using $MY_ENV_VAR or ${{ env.MY_ENV_VAR }}?
# workflow.yaml
 - name: create env var 1
   run: echo "OUTPUT1='odoyle rules'" >> $GITHUB_ENV

 - name: print all env vars
   run: cat $GITHUB_ENV

# console output
Run cat $GITHUB_ENV
  cat $GITHUB_ENV
  env:
    OUTPUT1: 'odoyle rules'  # <-- this is the var in the env, not the content of the file


What is your use case? What do you want to achieve?

I want to be able to capture all of the variables that have been written to $GITHUB_ENV during a job, without knowing the names of the vars. So i can iterate through the list, generically, without prior knowledge of what's in there.

You can use toJson(env) and jq.

Sure, but env includes all of the environment variables, including system-level ones. I want only the vars that were written to $GITHUB_ENV in any of a job’s steps.

I found a good way to do this using the steps context.
You can't do steps.*.outputs, or read the $GITHUB_OUTPUT file; but you can get a list of all the outputs by reading the entire steps context object:
Workflow:
# run a bunch of steps that create outputs
...
- name: print steps
  run: echo "${{ toJSON(steps) }}"

Output:
{
  out1: {
    outputs: {
      output1: "Hello, world!"
    },
    outcome: success,
    conclusion: success
  },
  out2: {
    outputs: {
      output2: "where am i"
    },
    outcome: success,
    conclusion: success
  }
}

$your-output-var | yq '.[].outputs'
{output1: "Hello, world!"}
{output2: "where am i"}


Note I'm using yq here, because the output in my case isn't valid JSON; it's YAML. Depending on where and how you're extracting the JSON from the context, you'll use either jq or yq; or your json parser of choice.

So you still have to parse the JSON and filter for the outputs, but it's at still an "official" way to access this data dynamically.
